# Windows Experience Index (WEI) / WinSAT results show all zeros on Windows 8.1 machine

Tags: windows-8.1, thinkpad, windows-experience-index

I am trying to calculate my WEI/WinSAT scores on a Windows 8.1 machine (Lenovo ThinkPad W530).  Since the WEI graphical user interface has been removed in Windows 8.1 I am using the command line procedure as documented at http://www.cnet.com/how-to/find-your-windows-experience-index-scores-in-windows-8-1/ and other places.

I first run:

```
winsat prepop
```

and the system goes to work (when I re-run the command, it returns immediately, not doing the calculations again.  how do I force it?) making the calculations.  Then I do:

```
Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_WinSAT
```

but when I get the results screen similar to the one shown below, all my values are 0 where the scores are shown.  What might be happening here?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Howiecamp

I don't know "Exactly" what can cause this zero result since it looks like a writing permission on the first run or simply a cache issue.

Anyway I tryed the app [ChrisPC Win Experience Index](http://win-experience-index.chris-pc.com/) and there the scores appear ok.

Just out of curiosity double checked on the Powershell and Voilá.... there they are now...

### Results Before run App

- CPUScore : 0
- D3DScore : 0
- DiskScore : 0
- GraphicsScore : 0
- MemoryScore : 0
- TimeTaken : MostRecentAssessment
- ***WinSATAssessmentState : 3***
- WinSPRLevel : 0

### Results After run App

- CPUScore : 6,7
- D3DScore : 3,7
- DiskScore : 5,6
- GraphicsScore : 4,1
- MemoryScore : 6,7
- TimeTaken : MostRecentAssessment
- ***WinSATAssessmentState : 1***
- WinSPRLevel : 3,7

Notice the change not only on the scores but also on **WinSATAssessmentState**

### WinSAT State Codes

- 0 = State Unknown
- 1 = Valid
- 2 = Incoherent With Hardware
- 3 = No Assessment Available
- 4 = Invalid

Let me know if it helps and share along your results.

Answer (score 2):

Here's what works for me, from the command prompt (<kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>, <kbd>C</kbd>):

- `winsat formal -restart`
- `powershell /c Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_WinSAT`